# In doctrine 2.1, how do I get all entities using many to many associations - all articles in several categories?

Tags: many-to-many, associations, doctrine-orm

I have a zend framework 1.11.11 application, using doctrine 2.1 (via bisna).
I have an Article and Category entities. Each article can be associated to many categories, each category can hold many articles.

I've created the following association in each of them:
Article:

```
/**
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="categoryArticles")
 * @JoinTable
 * (
 *      name="categories_articles",
 *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="article_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
 */
protected $categories;
```

Category:

```
/**
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Article", mappedBy="categories", cascade={"persist"})
 * @var ArrayCollection
 */
private $categoryArticles;
```

---

How can I get all the articles that belongs to a given array of categories ?
For example, I want to get all the articles that are associated with categories ids 1, 5 and 20.

The standard repository way ($this->findBy(array('categories' => array(1, 5, 20)))) doesn't work, dql way doesn't work (according to the tries I made) and I can't seem to think of another way.

Help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is with join/in:

```
<?php
$category_ids = array(1,2,5);
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('a')
    ->from('Article','a')
    ->join('a.categories','c')
    ->where($qb->expr()->in('c.id',$category_ids));
$articles = $qb->getQuery()->execute();
```